# Typescript array type extends a base array type

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to extend the type of an array, ie having at least the base array elements and possibly other elements.

use case: to communicate with translations APIs, I defined a base languages array:

```
const languages = ['FR', 'EN'] as const;
type BaseLanguages = typeof languages;
```

The objective is to define some derived types, arrays which contains at least 'FR' and 'EN' and possibly other string languages.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you want a type to have values in it. i don't think it's possible. but you can validate your derivations if they have  languages in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the spread operator can you help you here.

```
const languages = ['FR', 'EN'] as const;
type BaseLanguages = [...typeof languages, ...string[]];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=57&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgQzAcwK4OQUwjAvDAbQHIAxAJSIBoYiBRAOSIF0YEdRIoBuAKCgE8ADphgAhNpgAySNBmx5CAOmUDhIAGbwZ6LBGrLF0AE4BLFASZMuQA)